# How can I "redirect" to another URL and pass a list object using Flask

Tags: python, flask

I have a very basic question regarding URL changes.
Let's assume I have a HTML page `http://example.com/create` that conatins a form with some input fields. From this input fields I want to create a python list which should be used to generate another HTML page `http://example.com/show_list` containing a list based on the python's list values.

So the view for `http://example.com/create` is:

```
@app.route('/create', methods=['GET', 'POST']) 
def create():

if request.method == 'POST':
    some_list = parse_form_data_and_return_list(...)
    return render_template( "show_list.html", some_list=some_list)  #here's the problem!

return render_template( "create.html")
```

Assume that `parse_form_data_and_return_list(...)` takes the user input and returns a list with some `string` values.
I added a comment to the line that troubles me. I'll come back to it in a second but first give you the template of the page (`http://example.com/show_list`) that should be loaded AFTER the user input:

```
{% block content %}
<ul class="list">       
  {% for item in some_list %}
    <li>
        {{ item }}
    </li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endblock content %}
```

Basically this works fine. The list values are "passed" to the Jinja template and the list is shown.

If you now again have a look to my route method you can see that I am only doing `render_template` to show the `shwo_list` page. For me this has one disadvantage. The URL will not be changed to `http://example.com/show_list`, but will stay at `http://example.com/create`.

So I thought about creating a own `route` for `show_list` and in the `create()` method calling `redirect` instead of rendering the next template directly. Like this:

```
@app.route('/show_list')
def tasklist_foo():
return render_template( "show_list.html" )
```

But in this case I don't see how I could pass the `list` object to `show_list()`. I could of course parse every single item of the list to the URL (hence post it to `http://example.com/show_list`), but that's not what I want to do.

As you already might have recognized, I'm pretty new to web developing. I guess I just use a wrong pattern or haven't found a simple API function that does the trick. So I kindly ask you to show me a way to solve my problem (shortly summerized): render the `show_list` template and change the URL from `http://example.com/create` to `http://example.com/show_list` using the list created in the `create()` method/route.

Comment: Why should `/create` redirect to a URL that won't work after you refresh the page? That isn't very RESTful or user-friendly. Can you explain your current scenario in more detail?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If the list isnt very long, you could pass it on the query string, say comma separated:

```
comma_separated = ','.join(some_list)
return redirect(url_for('show_list', some_list=comma_separated))
# returns something like 'http://localhost/show_list?some_list=a,b,c,d'
```

Then in the template in your view, you can iterate over them like so:

```
{% for item in request.args.get('some_list', '').split(',') %}
    {{ item }}
{% endfor %}
```

For longer lists, or if you didnt want to expose it on the query string, you could also store the list in the [session](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/#sessions):

```
session['my_list'] = some_list
return redirect(url_for('show_list'))
```

Then in the template:

```
{% for item in session.pop('my_list', []) %}
    {{ item }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Ahhh! The session dict. That's it. How could I have overseen this? I guess just too much new information for today. Thank you mate!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to storing the list in the session you could also simply change your form action to post to the new route.  Then process the form data from within the 'show_list' route and render your template.

Form heading:

```
<form action="{{ url_for('show_list') }}" method="post">
```

Updated show_list route:

```
@app.route('/show_list', methods=['GET', 'POST']) 
def show_list():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        some_list = parse_form_data_and_return_list(...)
        return render_template("show_list.html")
    else:
        # another way to show your list or disable GET
        return render_template("show_list.html")
```

I'm not necessarily opposed to using session storage, but I think it's cleaner to not use it as you don't have to worry about clearing your session variables.